# why addClass && removrClass jquery not work

Tags: dom, jquery

why this code not work? do this methods only work with css?

```
<input type="button" class="one" value="click Me" />
<input type="button" value="change Class" id="clk" />

<script>
$("#clk").click(function () {
    $('[value = "click Me"]').removeClass('one').addClass('tow');
    alert($('[value = "click Me"]').attr('class')); //print tow
});
$(".one").click(function () {
    alert('one');
});
$(".tow").click(function () {
    alert('tow');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can find the answer by reading the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using event delegation *As class `tow` doesn't exist when you are binding click event to it*

```
$(document.body).on('click',".tow",function(){
      alert('tow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', '.one', function (event) {
    alert('one');
});
$('body').on('click', '.tow', function (event) {
    alert('tow');
});
```

Comment: Code without explanation is rarely helpful.

Comment: thanks friend. solved my problom